# TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray' - How to fix this error when doing a query()

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

> I am trying to run a simple query() on this dataframe but I am getting
>   this error at the query statement: "TypeError: unhashable type:
>   'numpy.ndarray'"
>
> I am pretty sure this is a simple error but I have checked through the
>   other answers available and I am not able to understand what needs to
>   be done here.
>
> Thanks a lot in advance!

---

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#creating a dataframe 

data = {'model': ['Lisa', 'Lisa 2', 'Macintosh 128K', 'Macintosh 512K'],
        'launched': [1983,1984,1984,1984],
        'discontinued': [1986, 1985, 1984, 1986]
        }

df3 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['model', 'launched', 'discontinued'])

#printing only a query subset of the dataframe 

print(df3.query('model.str.contains("acin",case=False)==False'))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

as of [Pandas 0.24](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) you need to add `engine='python'` to your argument:

```
print(df3.query('model.str.contains("acin")',engine='python'))
out:
            model  launched  discontinued
2  Macintosh 128K      1984          1984
3  Macintosh 512K      1984          1986
```